# Websocket won't reconnect unless I close the browser tab and restart it

Tags: javascript, websocket, esp8266

I have a webserver with websockets set up on an ESP8266.  The application runs fine on both client and server sides, sending and receiving data.  However, if the server side disconnects (power cycle or upload new code), the client (Chrome) won't reconnect to the websocket.  I can reload/refresh the web page, and it claims (according to the console log) to be connecting to the websocket, but it does not.  The only solution I have found that works is to close the tab, and then restart a new session.

My code is heavily based on this tutorial from [Random Nerd Tutorials](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-nodemcu-websocket-server-arduino/)

```
var gateway = `ws://${window.location.hostname}/ws`;
var websocket;

function initWebSocket() {
  console.log('Trying to open a WebSocket connection...');
  websocket = new WebSocket(gateway);
  websocket.onopen    = onOpen;
  websocket.onclose   = onClose;
  websocket.onmessage = onMessage; // <-- add this line
}

function onOpen(event) {
  console.log('Connection opened');
}

function onClose(event) {
  console.log('Connection closed');
  setTimeout(initWebSocket, 2000);
}
```

Is there something that is missing from the code above to make it more reliable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use **setInterval**. Try this, you may have to tweek it a bit.

```
var gateway = `ws://${window.location.hostname}/ws`;
var websocket, sockTimer=null;

function initWebSocket() {
  console.log('Trying to open a WebSocket connection...');
  websocket = new WebSocket(gateway);
  websocket.onopen    = onOpen;
  websocket.onerror    = onError;    //  new
  websocket.onclose   = onClose;
  websocket.onmessage = onMessage; // <-- add this line
}

function onOpen(event) {    
  clearInterval(sockTimer) // <= better
  console.log('Connection opened');

}
function onError() {   // <= New
       sockTimer = setInterval(init, 1000 * 60);
                
};
function onClose(event) {
  console.log('Connection closed');
  //setTimeout(initWebSocket, 2000);
sockTimer = setInterval(initWebSocket, 1000 * 60); // <=new
}
```

Comment: Would onError() need to close the socket before starting it anew?

Comment: I think no, not sure, at least  I don't close it.

Comment: So, if I understand `setInterval()`, once `onClose()` triggers, then it will keep calling `initWebSocket()` every 60 seconds....forever.

Comment: Not forever  because in the onOpen() the inteval will be cleared.